# IBM Worklight - How to silently update the application's web resources?

Tags: updates, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I want to silently update the web resources of my application using the *Direct Update* feature.

I did not manage to find any related documentation to do that.
Can anyone give me an idea on how         to proceed?

1. I generated an apk for my application say app version 1.0.
2. With some modifications in UI I generated one more apk say version 1.1.
3. Now again with some change i generated apk for third version say v 1.2.(latest)

Now My intention is if a user has apk 1.0 then it should update the user that this version is deprecated and i will provide a link to get the latest version.
  If the user has apk version 1.1 then it has to alert the user that an update is available.
All these things I am able to achieve using direct update. But when I am trying the same for silent update it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [property you're looking for](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_init.html) is `updateSliently` set to `true` in initOptions.js.
For this to work, it is required that `connectOnStartup` will be set to `true` as well.

It seems to be working in Worklight 6.0, but fail in Worklight 5.0.6; I have opened a defect for this.

In any case,
The steps you have described are INCORRECT. These are the steps for Direct Update, silent or not:

1. Create an app, add environment
2. Build all and deploy
3. Launch app on device
4. Change WEB RESOURCES in the app (images, HTML, JavaScript)
5. Re-build and deploy the app
6. Re-open the app / bring it back to the foreground

If you are changing the version id, the changes you will make to the web resources will not reach their destination.

Changes done to version="1.0", will reach only apps running version "1.0"; if you up the value then changes will only reach apps of that new value.

Comment: so in my initOptions.js i need to give updateSilently : true. Is it the one you are mentioning sir?

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying, yes.

Comment: I am not able to get silent updates eventhough i added updateSilently:true in my initOptions.js file

Comment: Works fine for me. Make sure that connectOnStartup (as well in initOptions.js) is set to "true", otherwise the app will not connect to the Worklight Server, thus Direct Update will not work.

Comment: I set onConnectionStartUp : true also.For direct update it is working fine. But silent update is not working ...

Comment: Worked for me in Worklight 6.0. What is your Worklight version?

Comment: my version is 5.0.6 sir

Comment: Explain in the question the steps you're taking in order to sliently updating the app.

Comment: ooks like this fails in 5.0.6 but works in 6.0 - in 5.0.6 that app does not fully load... did you notice that? I will open a defect.

Comment: Your steps are very much incorrect(!). See my updated answer.

Comment: If i give onConnectionStartUP : true and run the app it is giving me an error "the application failed connecting to the service"

Comment: @Avinash, sorry, I don't know what you're doing. There is also no such property "onConnectionStartUP".

Comment: Sir, I specified  connectOnStartup : true in initOption.js

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but you're doing it wrong. If you are an IBMer, contact me on SameTime.

Comment: I got it. I understood where I went wrong. I am confused in initOptions.js file. I tried it from the scratch following the steps provided by you sir.Its working now.